# Get the penultimate observable of a chained map() call in Rx Java

Tags: java, rx-java

I have two observables:

1. `Observable<User> createUser(UserData userData)`
2. `Observable<Void> loginUser(User user)`

After the user creates a new account I wish to login with that new account. So I've done this:

```
createUser(userData).map(user -> loginUser(user));
```

But in that way, I get an `Observable<Void>` as return. What I want to do is to call `createUser(userData).map(user -> loginUser(user))` and get an `Observable<User>` as return. Something like this:

```
@Override
public Observable<User> createUserAndLogin(){

    createUser(userData).map(user -> loginUser(user));

}
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use log-in as a side-effect with [`doOnNext`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext%28rx.functions.Action1%29)?

```
createUser(userData).doOnNext(user -> loginUser(user));
```

If you want to make sure the log-in happened:

```
createUser(userData).flatMap(user -> {
    // attach a callback to the log-in and return
    // the user from the previous call
    return loginUser(user).map(dontCare -> user);
});
```

But I'm not sure how it's going to work if `loginUser` emits nothing, so perhaps forcibly concat the value you want to the empty `loginUser` observable:

```
 createUser(userData).flatMap(user -> {
    // attach a callback to the log-in and return
    // the user from the previous call
    return loginUser(user).concatWith(Observable.just(user));
});
```

Comment: great! But one more question: If I want to execute some code in onNext() and onError() methods of the loginUser Observable, how could I combine them with the createUser Observable? Because I want to show a message if the loginUser Observable throws an error and another message if the loginUser Observables succeeds *i.e.* **createUser == Ok and Login == Ok -> OperationSuccessfull -> return User** and **createUser == Ok and Login == Error -> Error return null and show erro message**

Comment: If you need the result to have an effect on the chain of observables **don't** use a side-effect `Observable.doOnX`. Once you choose one of the none-side-effect methods you can use `Observable.onErrorX` to handle whatever unexpected errors asynchronously. Read this for more information: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling